# Can someone tell me which sentence is grammatically correct between the two?

Tags: grammaticality, syntactic-analysis, british-english, sentence

Is it

> Pacific Ocean is the largest and **the** deepest ocean in the world

or

> Pacific Ocean is the largest and deepest ocean in the world

Comment: _The_ Pacific Ocean. The second sounds better to me.

Comment: Is there some rule behind it?

Comment: Neither is wrong, but the second flows better. More importantly, they should both start "The Pacific . . ."

Comment: Both are wrong because _the Pacific Ocean_ requires _the_. Aside from that, both are fine; conjunction reduction is optional.

Comment: Including the (third) 'the' works inasmuch as it adds emphasis, gravitas; the deleted version flows better but is less punchy.

Answer (score -3):

The first sentence 
 I.e. *The Pacific ocean is the largest and deepest ocean in the world* is right.
Yes, there are some guidelines to use 'the' in a sentence...as 'the' is a definite article. Also “The” is used in the superlative degree. Please use 'the' in starting of the sentence

Comment: Could you please provide some source to support this?

Comment: @Rattler No problem sir..

Comment: @Rattler I apologize for that , I'll keep this thing in mind.

Comment: No problem...and welcome aboard!

Comment: @Rattler  Thank you sir for your guidelines ...as I'm new to this ..I didn't new.

Comment: The Pacific ocean should be capitalised, and in neither of the examples cited by the OP, do they use the definite article in front of the proper noun. This, in part, probably explains the high number of downvotes...